# r subset/filter/select group based on two values in same vector

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to subset/filter/select/etc by group based on two values in the same vector. Specifically, I am trying to get all x groups that have a y of less than 0.5 AND a y of greater than 1. I'd also love to be able to do this based on factors, but baby steps I guess. This is my first post, please be gentle ha ha.

```
#Fake Data

library(tidyverse)

x<-c("Luke", "Luke", "Luke", "Luke", 
 "Leia", "Leia", "Leia", "Leia",
 "Anakin", "Anakin", "Anakin", "Anakin",
 "Obi", "Obi", "Obi", "Obi",
 "Han", "Han", "Han", "Han")

y<-c(0.1, 0.4, 5.4, 3.2,
     0.4, 0.3, 1.9, 10.0,
     10.2, 8.5, 1.7, 5.4,
     0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2,
     11.1, 15.3, 5.8, 6.9)

z<-c(1, 2, 3, 4,
     5, 6, 7, 8,
     9, 10, 11, 12,
     13, 14, 15, 16,
     17, 18, 19, 20)

star<-data.frame(x, y, z)

twotest<-star %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(y<0.5 & y>1.0) %>%
  arrange(x)
summary(twotest$x)
```

I get

```
Anakin    Han   Leia   Luke    Obi 
     0      0      0      0      0
```

but would love to get just Leia and Luke.

Comment: In your example, `Han` doesn\t have any value less than 0.5.  Perhaps `star %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(any(any(y < 0.5) & y > 1))` but it won't include 'Han'

Comment: Try `filter(any(y<0.5) & any(y>1.0))`.

Comment: Thank you, akrun and MrFlick!!! Both of these worked!!! Sorry, I did not mean to include Han.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use intersect:

```
dplyr::intersect(star[star$y<0.5,"x"],star[star$y>1,"x"])
```